# SQLite Index Before Appending Rows

Tags: sqlite, indexing

If I create an index on some columns in an SQLite table then append rows to the table after that, do I have to delete and recreate the index or will the index update automatically? What if I delete rows?

Comment: Indexes are automatically updated when you insert, delete, or update rows.

Comment: It's rather a question about SQL. Indexes are automatically managed because index is really a pointer to data. So don't put indexes on frequently changing data and when there are many null values.

What's more, SQLite automatically assumes indexes on each UNIQUE column, including PRIMARY KEY. Line operations (delete, insert, update) cause table fragmentation. To get rid of fragmentation, issue the VACUUM command;
For this reason, you should not rely on the automatic system index of the SQLite database, just create your own id field and give it a basic index with auto-increment.